# How do i screen record on my device?

Tags: recovery-mode

I have an Amazon Fire HD8, and I need to know how to screen record the best way possible! Please help, because I'm a fairly newer youtuber, and I don't know what I'm doing, honestly!

Answer (score 2):

You would need a third party app to record your screen. Install any screen recording app from the play store and enjoy.

I personally like one that's called [AZ screen recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hecorat.screenrecorder.free) it records your screen, and gives some nice options with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many screen recording applications on Google Play Store. Try various apps and find out which one best suits you. Use this Android Authority [link](https://www.androidauthority.com/best-screen-recording-apps-600838/), where you can find some apps.